# signalR client without jQuery?

Tags: jquery, signalr

I am writing a mobile application sing Titanium. I use SignalR because the server is written in C#, but I need to run the signalR client in a webview on the phone. My question is if there is any implementation of SignalR client that does not require JQuery

Comment: Does the webview not just load up an html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is if there is any implementation of SignalR client that
>   does not require JQuery

Those are the available [`Signalr clients`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src) for various platforms:

- [`Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.JS`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.JS) (jQuery plugins for Signalr)
- [`Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Silverlight5`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Silverlight5) (for Silverlight 5 clients)
- [`Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.WP8`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.WP8) (for Windows Phone 8 clients)
- [`Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.WinRT`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.WinRT) (for WinRT clients)
- [`Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client) (for .NET clients - full framework)
- [`Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client45`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client45) (for .NET 4.5 clients - full framework)

In your question you seem to be talking about some *webview* and some *phone* without giving any specifics but if this is a Windows Phone application there's a `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.WP8` just for you. If this is some other platform you will have to check the documentation whether it has some WebSockets implementations available for it if there are not official client implementations for it.

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer is no. Not yet at least.

Comment: This was in February. What about now? Can you use TypeScript or plain JavaScript instead of jQuery?

Comment: Nothing has changed. We're gradually removing our jquery dependency as we make changes and we hope to have it fully removed in 2.1 (and no I don't have a date for 2.1 yet)

Comment: What does SignalR rely on jQuery to do?

Comment: ajax, deferred, events

Comment: @davidfowl i see we are at version 2.2.0.  Jquery is still required?

Comment: @davidfowl any news on that?

Comment: @Sagivb.g I know it's an old topic but there's signalr-no-jquery and @types/signalr-no-jquery